# Leak in cvFlip() or something i messed up

Tags: java, memory-leaks, javacv

I'm trying to implement a simple application to show my webcamera, which works good, until I try to flip the output stream. After I'm flipping the stream the program starts to leak. The strange its only leak when I flip the stream and I have no idea why, since I try to release everything. When I dont flip, the leak is gone. (Its still leaks when I comment out all the release lines)

I'm getting my image source from `GrabCamera` through these methods:

```
private void StartWebcamera(){
    cameraThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
                while ((grabbedImage = opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture)) != null) {
                    grabbedImage.release();
            }   
        }
    };
    cameraThread.start();
}

public IplImage GetGrabbedStream(){
    return grabbedImage;
}
```

In my main i pass the image to my GUI class like these:

```
while (true) {
        gui.SetVideoStream(grabCamera.GetGrabbedStream(), true);//if true its leaking if false its not leaking
}
```

And I show my image in the GUI class:

```
public void SetVideoStream(IplImage img,boolean flip){
    if (flip) {
        IplImage mirrorImage = img.clone();
        cvFlip(img, mirrorImage, 1);
        cameraFeed.setImage(mirrorImage.getBufferedImage());
        videoPanel.setIcon(cameraFeed);
        videoPanel.repaint();
        mirrorImage.release();
        img.release();
    }
    else {
        cameraFeed.setImage(img.getBufferedImage());
        videoPanel.setIcon(cameraFeed);
        videoPanel.repaint();
        img.release();
    }
}
```

Here are the complete classes:
[Classes](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t5enaf64l2bwyb7/AAA1-aM1imhvJ7GZAiNs-2dLa?dl=0)

Comment: Set -XMX & -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError values. Create heap dump and analyze it with Eclipse Memory analyser. It tells too more information. If XMX too big, you are waiting too much, if set too small, you are not recognize to symptoms.

Comment: Offtopic, all functions should start with lowercase characters.

Comment: I did the heap dump and it's said the possible leak is: •org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer$DeallocatorReference @ 0xff78ef78 - 231 352 (3,01%) bytes.  ,but I don't really know what to do with this.(the dump file: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ljwenlq26kwt8t/java_pid10992.hprof?dl=0) )
@Seega Thanks, I will take your advice.